# .htaccess to remove index.php and subfolder from URL

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I am an .htaccess newbie and am having problems in removing a folder name from my sites URL.

It is currently: www.mydomain.com/engine

I have an expression engine site in a subfolder (named engine) of my hosts html folder. In this folder I have an htaccess document in which I have followed the directions in the expressionengine user guide to remove the index.php? from the URL succesfully, with:

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I would now like to remove the "engine" referring to the subfolder from the URL too.

I have made numerous attempts going on advice in previous questions but have had no success.

On viewing www.mydomain.com, with any of my attempts I recieve:

Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I thought this could be a permissions problem, but this containing html folder has the same permissions as the "engine" folder which allows access.

Can anybody help with the .htaccess code i require?

Comment: add `/engine/`  before index.php in your rewriterule and move the code  to your root directory (one level up).

Comment: thanks Amine, I have updated the htaccess in the html folder and created an htaccess file one level up to include the /engine/ and this works for all pages but the homepage. For example mydomain.com/page1 works but mydomain.com is still giving me the: Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server. warning. Is this a problem with my htaccess or my permissions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

yeh, the above rules don't apply to homepage url because it's a directory (doesn't pass the third `RewriteCond`), use the code below:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond $1 ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /engine/index.php?/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amine, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Amine, I am still having problems and was wondering if you would be able to help me. The site is live at jesuisunemonstre.com and I have managed to remove most cases of "engine" by using the htaccess you suggested and switching from using expressionengine path links to normal URL's however there area couple of areas where this isnt possible due to the way the links are generated by expressionengine. With the htaccess above should that be able to remove every instance of "engine" from the URL? I have fiddled with this for hours and hours but had no joy.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!